# Microsoft Graph API Javascript SDK Promises

Tags: javascript, async-await

I just got rid of the promise chaining as it was very confusing and went ahead with async await. I'm still not able to get the required results. How do I get the result of finalResult() from the below code. It keeps returning promise pending. I tried doing the following

let sampleData = await finalResult()

Here how do I get the data from sampleData? I also tried attaching a then call to finalResult which didn't work either. Any help pls? All I need is the channelData in the code below

```
app.get("/graph/getChannelEvents", (req, res) => {
  var idToken = req.query.idToken;
  var teamId = req.query.teamId;
  var channelData = req.query.channelData;
  var tenantId = process.env.TENANT_ID;
  if (!idToken) {
    res.status(500).send("Could not find id token");
    return;
  }
  request(
    `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      form: {
        grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        client_id: process.env.APP_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.APP_Secret,
        scope: "Calendars.Read",
        requested_token_use: "on_behalf_of",
        assertion: idToken,
      },
    },
    async (error, response, body) => {
      const accessToken = JSON.parse(body)["access_token"];

      var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
        defaultVersion: "v1.0",
        debugLogging: true,
        authProvider: (done) => {
          done(null, accessToken);
        },
      });

      async function finalResult() {
        let cdata = await client
          .api(`/groups/${teamId}/events`)
          .header("Prefer", 'outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"')
          .select("subject,onlinemeeting,start,end")
          .get();
        let channelData = await cdata.value.map(async (org) => {
          var channelId = url
            .parse(decodeURIComponent(org.onlineMeeting.joinUrl))
            .pathname.split("/")[3];
          var sessionData = await client
            .api(`/teams/${teamId}/channels`)
            .filter(`startswith(id, '${channelId}')`)
            .select("displayName")
            .get();
          let myData = await sessionData.value.map(async (u) => {
            return {
              sessionName: org.subject,
              channelName: u.displayName,
              channelId: channelId,
              startDate: org.start.dateTime.split("T")[0],
              endDate: org.end.dateTime.split("T")[0],
              startTime: org.start.dateTime.split("T")[1],
              endTime: org.end.dateTime.split("T")[1],
            };
          });
        });
        console.log(channelData);
      }

      finalResult();
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this would be to make it asynchronously with a promise wrapping the whole shown code and returning that promise with a function.

After that you would want to make an array of promises to be able to call them all at once and wait for all the results before continuing. you use `Promise.all()` to call all the promises in the array and use it as you would use a single promise with a `.then()`. The received value from that then() would be an array containing all of the results from the promiseArray's promises.

```
var getStuff = () => {
    //First and big promise starts here
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        client.api(`/groups/${teamId}/events`)
            .header("Prefer", 'outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"')
            .select("subject,onlinemeeting,start,end")
            .get()
            .then((result) => {
                // Create an array for your promises
                var promisesArray = [];
                result.value.map((org) => {
                    // Fill your array with every promise you need, each one containing just one call to your api
                    promisesArray.push(new Promise((arrayResolve, arrayReject) => {
                        console.log("top: " + org.subject);
                        var channelId = url
                        .parse(decodeURIComponent(org.onlineMeeting.joinUrl))
                        .pathname.split("/")[3];
                        client
                        .api(`/teams/${teamId}/channels`)
                        .filter(`startswith(id, '${channelId}')`)
                        .select("displayName")
                        .get()
                        .then((result) => {
                            const cdata = result.value.map((u) => {
                            console.log("down " + org.subject);
                            return {
                                sessionName: org.subject,
                                channelName: u.displayName,
                                channelId: channelId,
                                startDate: org.start.dateTime.split("T")[0],
                                endDate: org.end.dateTime.split("T")[0],
                                startTime: org.start.dateTime.split("T")[1],
                                endTime: org.end.dateTime.split("T")[1],
                            };
                            });
                        })
                        .then((result) => {
                            // Resolve individual promises
                            arrayResolve(result);
                        }).catch((err) => {
                            reject(err);
                        })
                    }));
                })
                // This executes all the promises at the same time
                Promise.all(promisesArray).then( (finalResult) => {
                    // Resolve big and initial promise
                    resolve(finalResult);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                })
        })
    })
}
```

(NOTE: I just wrapped your existing code in a function and completed the braces and parenthesis needed. Then I added the promises that would make this work as intended but some code needs to be added to make it work, as i noticed you called some variables that weren't defined inside your shown code)

After this, you could just call this function and use a '.then()' to receive the value you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've modified my previous code with async/await now and re-posted it in the forum, but it still doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are committing a similar mistake in your new code. You are now not collecting the results and returning them. Your `channelData` variable is not going to receive anything because the first map function is not returning anything! Also, your function `finalResult` isn't returning anything either.